# Why does the list returned by librosa.feature.rms() have so few values?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa

I have audio data from a file that lasts a second :

```
audiodata, rate = librosa.load(datafile, sr=None, mono=True)
```

Having a sample rate of 44100 Hz, the resulting list has 44100 values.

But when computing the RMS value for each frame like so :

```
rms = librosa.feature.rms(y=audiodata)
```

rms only has 87 values. Why is it so and how do I get more values ?

I tried to halve the frame length :

```
rms = librosa.feature.rms(y=audiodata, frame_length=1024)
```

But the number of data is the exact same while I expected it to change.

Here is how I tested it :

```
amp = rms[0]
print("number of audio data : ", len(audiodata))
print("number of RMS data : ", len(amp))
```

and the output is

```
number of audio data :  44100
number of RMS data :  87
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `hop_length` parameter, not `frame_length` to change number of outputs. Take a look at [documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.rms.html)

```
rms = librosa.feature.rms(y=audiodata, hop_length=32)
print(rms.shape)
```

```
(1, 1379)
```